# Win 8.1 // WebView // Handle custom protocol on HTTR 302 redirect

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, custom-url

I'm on the way to upgrade a windows 8 application to 8.1. A new feature should be a checkout process using a WebView. In some cases the server responds a HTTP 302 Code and the webview is redirected to an url with a custom protocol (e.g. customer://checkout) which I can not handle.
Tried these events to catch the redirect.

NavigationStarting
NavigationFailed
FrameNavigationStarting
UnviewableContentIdentified

So the next try was to seperate the WebView from its http client and load the content using the NavigateToString method with the html I get from my own HttpClient. 
As there are form data I have to submit using a post request and there's no way to use a InvokeScriptNotify / ScriptNotify, this way might also not work.

Does anyone have an idea how to handel a redirect or recognize a submit of form data without ScriptNotify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the events firing for non 302s?

Comment: Yes, the events are fired on every navigation, except the redirect. It seems the redirect is handled by the webview in background

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is likely happening on your ecommerce site.  I ran into a similar issue, and found that my commerce site was redirecting because it thought that a cookie should be present when it wasn't.

Are you setting the src on the x-ms-webview element and then later navigating the webview in code?  This could cause a double navigation event and potentially not set your web apps state appropriately.